# Where should utils function and constants define, top-level or object(single instance)?

Tags: java, kotlin

Is there a best practice / convention for utils function and constants, top-level or object(single instance)?

If use top-level, For example, the file utils.kt, we can't write comment for utils.kt, callers may not know what relationship and belong about those functions and constants.

If use object(single instance), then any kotlin code will like:

```
Xxx.xxx
```

What would be best?

Comment: Actually, even with objects, you can use a namespace import and call the functions without specifying the object name: `import com.example.Xxx.*`.

Comment: From a talk by one of jetbrain's employees: https://github.com/yole/idiomatic-kotlin/tree/master/src/main/kotlin/p02_classesAndFunctions/t05_ToplevelFunctions  (if you're confused about the order, it's good > better > bad).

Comment: @Michael why good > better ?

Comment: @Michael is better for bad, not for good ?

Comment: I'm not talking about the meaning of the words; I was just clarifying that that was the order intended by the author of those examples.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this will help. but you can use companion object inside your util class to access them as if they were static methods.. take a look at this example [on how to use companion object to achieve static method like behavior in kotlin](https://github.com/bilaleluneis/LearningKotlin/blob/master/src/basics/CompanionObject.kt)

```
class ClassWithCompanionObject {

constructor() {
    numberOfInstancesOfClass++
    println("create instance number $numberOfInstancesOfClass of ClassWithCompanionObject")
}

/**
 * companion Object is a singleton object
 * so only one instance of it is created..
 * similar to Java Static block .. Kotlin doesn't
 * have static. so everything inside a companion
 * object can be thought of as static and will be
 * initialized only once. or you can think of it
 * as class level instead on instance level.
 */
companion object {

    private var numberOfInstancesOfClass = 0

    fun printNumberOfInstancesOfClassValue(){
        println("numberOfInstancesOfClass = $numberOfInstancesOfClass !")
    }
 }

}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {

ClassWithCompanionObject()
ClassWithCompanionObject()
ClassWithCompanionObject()
ClassWithCompanionObject.printNumberOfInstancesOfClassValue()

}
```

Comment: When answering a question please include the relevant code or explanation in your answer rather than providing a link to an external resource which may later become unavailable, thank you :)